# Mouse message handling in win32

Tags: c++, oop, winapi

[image]

When a user clicks on window B the window C becomes visible.

**Situation 1** : While window C is visible and user clicks anywhere on window A or B or any other child windows of window A, window C becomes invisible.

**Situation 2** : While window C is visible and user clicks on window C then program does few things and makes window C invisible. [window C has more child windows]

How do I achieve this functionality ?

The SetCapture won't work for Situation 2.

In the window B this is what I got, it works for Situation 1, but obviously not for Situation 2.

```
LRESULT WindowB::LButtonDown ( HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    if ( !capture )
    {
        ::SetCapture ( hwnd );
        capture = true;
        windowC->show (  );
    }
    else
    {
        ::ReleaseCapture (  );
        capture = false;
        windowC->hide (  );
    }
    return 0;
};
```

**P.S : I am using pure winapi with oop c++, and my own wrapper for windows and message handling.**

EDIT: More code added as requested.

```
LRESULT WindowC::lButton ( UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{


    doStuff (  );

    ::PostMessage (  hParent, WM_COMMAND, WPARAM ( BN_CLICKED ), LPARAM ( hwnd )  );

    return 0;


};
```

Comment: Situation 2 make no sense for me. Why should a windows be hidden if I click on it? And what did you mean by make visible? Show/Hide or set to foreground/background?

Comment: @bkausbk think of window C like a drop down menu, when you click on an item, program do something and simultaneously makes window C (drop down menu) invisible. Show/Hide.

Comment: Show us your WindowC::LButtonDown.

Comment: BTW, you say *parent* and *child* windows, but surely you mean *owner* and *owned* windows.  They are completely different. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/15/9978691.aspx

Comment: To be clear: these windows are all modeless, right?  And do you actually care about the mechanism of *clicking* on windows or about the action of *activating* windows?  For example, you might be able to activate other windows via the keyboard or by simply moving the mouse (if focus-follows-mouse is enabled).

Comment: @jamesdlin my bad, Window C is a popup window while window A is the main window and window B is child (WS_CHILD) of window A. I am interested in mouse click only, either WM_LBUTTONDOWN or WM_LBUTTONUP

Comment: @Ben there's nothing much, but I have edited the original post and added the requested code.

Comment: You will need to pick off these mouse messages in your message loop.

Comment: @RaymondChen How do you do that ?

Comment: Um, not sure what more there is to say. In your message loop, look for mouse messages.